# Conditionals with NaN in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which I have to do the following:

I have to change the values that are null in the column `df["a"]` change them by dividing the values of the column `df["b"]/df["c "]`
`df["a"] =df["b"]/df["c"]` and if this value is not null leave it as is.

But before that I have to select the values that are different from `"USD"` and `NAN` in the column `df["e"]`, what I proposed was the following:

```
if  (df['e'].notnull()) | (df['e']!= 'USD') & (df['a'].isnull()):
    df['a']=(df['b']/ df['ac']) 
else:
    df['a']= df['a']
```

Comment: Please translate the title to English

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataframe. Kindly read this before ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't see any tests for NaN in the code you present here.

Comment: Try `np.where`.